# error installing ruby 2.3 on osx

Tags: macos, rvm, ruby-2.3

I'm getting an error while trying to install 2.3 ruby on osx
I've updated rvm to stable `1.27.0`

then I'm trying to install `2.3`

```
% rvm install 2.3
ruby-2.3.0 - #removing src/ruby-2.3.0 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/password123/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.0 - #downloading ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.0 - #extracting ruby-2.3.0 to /Users/password123/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0 - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/password123/.rvm/log/1460728216_ruby-2.3.0/make.log
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ossl_ssl.c:18:35: note: expanded from macro 'numberof'
#define numberof(ary) (int)(sizeof(ary)/sizeof((ary)[0]))
                                  ^~~~~
ossl_ssl.c:2266:21: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'const struct (anonymous struct at ossl_ssl.c:85:14) []'
    for (i = 0; i < numberof(ossl_ssl_method_tab); i++) {
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ossl_ssl.c:18:35: note: expanded from macro 'numberof'
#define numberof(ary) (int)(sizeof(ary)/sizeof((ary)[0]))
                                  ^~~~~
4 warnings and 10 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Could you advise me any steps to fix this error ?

Comment: Possibly related to [this rbenv issue](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/898)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [this rbenv discussion](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/898), I was able to work around this by uninstalling, reinstalling, and force-linking Homebrew OpenSSL:

```
brew uninstall --force openssl
brew install openssl
brew link --overwrite openssl --force
rvm install 2.3.0
```

I'd feel better if I knew what side effects the `brew link` might have, but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me:

Restart osx, then

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew unlink openssl098
brew install openssl
brew link --overwrite --force openssl
rvm install 2.3.0 # (or rvm install 2.3.1)
```

Based on https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3656

Comment: Help, me again. NOTE: You can ignore warning (brew link --overwrite --force openssl):
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Answer (score 4):

### **For Macbook M1 or M2:**

Please run the below command:

```
 export optflags="-w"
 arch -arm64 rvm install 2.5.3
 brew install openssl@1.1

 export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
 export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

 rvm autolibs disable

 export RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC
 export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

 rvm install 2.5.3 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1
```

again, you can change the ruby version from 2.3.0 to X.X.X in the above line.

This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Still getting the same error after running the lines mentionned,
Finally I solved my problem by updating hombrew, then uninstall and install openssl, then rvm install ruby 2.3 again

Answer (score 0):

There are issues installing ruby <=2.3.0 compatibility with Openssl@1.1.

This worked for me

```
rvm install 2.3.0 --with-openssl-lib=/opt/local/lib/openssl --with-openssl-include=/opt/local/include/openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL 1.1 isn’t compatible with Ruby 2.3.x checkout this issue [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3862)

I solved the issue on mac by using following command.

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.8 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.0` --debug
```

If you want more insights on the issue you can refer to this article https://mentalized.net/journal/2019/09/13/ruby-2-3-rvm-and-openssl-1-0/